# Simple File I/O in C++ - Never Exits This Loop?

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm a programming student in my second OOP class, my first class was taught in C# and this class is taught in C++. To get our feet wet in C++, our professor has asked us to write a rather large program with File I/O. The problem is, I have a small part of my program that is not working, at least, not for me. The project requires that we code a loop to test if the file could be opened successfully, and the loop I have written doesn't seem to be working.

I don't get any compiler errors, but when I enter in the path to the file, either relative or absolute, it says it's invalid. I have a feeling it has something to do with my conditions in my `do-while` loop, but I can't pinpoint it.

I don't mean to bring my homework to SO, but I've been scratching my head for two+ hours, and I can't seem to figure this out.

Would you mind helping me fix my loop? And maybe explain what it is that I'm doing wrong? I want to learn.

***Thanks!***

**Code:**

```
Rainfall rData;
ifstream actualReader;
ifstream averageReader;
string aRDataLoc;
char response = 'a';
const int KILL_VALUE = 1;
double actualRainfallD;
double actualRainfallPassedArray[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
double averageRainfallPassedArray[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
int i = 0;

do
{
    actualReader.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease enter in the path to the file containing the actual rainfall  data." << endl;
    cout << "Path to file: ";
    cin >> aRDataLoc;
    actualReader.open(aRDataLoc.c_str());
      if (!actualReader.is_open())
          {
            cout << "Invalid file path! Would you like to enter in a new file path?(y/n): ";
            cin >> response;
            if (response == 'n') { exit(KILL_VALUE); }
    }
}while (!actualReader.is_open() && response == 'y');
```

Comment: Can't help if we can't see the variables declared.

Comment: Its working fine for me. If I enter a non-exiting filename, it prompts to continue or not. If I enter a existing filename, it exits. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what line it is failing on?  Or is the file just never opening?  Also, you should be passing a mode to ifstream.open().... eg: actualReader.open(aRDataLoc.c_str(), ifstream::in).  Also, make sure that aRDataLoc is what you expect it to be when you hit that point in the program.

Comment: Also make sure you close the file when done with it...

Comment: Does the filename contain spaces?  Did you type the filename extension as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what input you are giving to `cin`, but be aware that `cin` will stop at the first whitespace character it encounters. For example, if you give as input the following:

```
C:\Program Files\directory
```

then `aRDataLog` would have the value `C:\Program` .

In order to read the whole line, you could use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/).

Check also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583652/how-to-read-cin-with-whitespace-up-until-a-newline-character).

Comment: +1. Also worth noting that `std::cin` doesn't know or respect the normal way to delimit a path (with "s).

Comment: Thank you! Cin was stopping at whitespace for my `visual studio 2008` directory. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not exactly sure what the issue is here, it might be a good idea to print what you're getting from `std::cin` to ensure you're getting what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put actualReader.close call in else, as the file has open handles and it is not available for open again