# Trying to find the middle initial of a name

Tags: c++, char

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char sampleName[30];
    char middle;
    int i;

    cin>>sampleName;

    for(i=0;i<30;i++){
        if(sampleName[i]=='.'){
            middle=sampleName[i-1];
            break;
        }          
    }

    cout<<middle;

    return 0;
    }
```

It doesn't seem to work though when the input has spaces in it. Please. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: can you paste sample input and output which you have tried and which is not working?

Comment: The input "JohnS.Smith" works. (Outputs 'S')
The input "John S. Smith" does not. (Outputs ' ')

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces

It's stopping at the space

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what your expected input is, but you may wish to look into `std::getline` (in conjunction with `std::string`) to avoid whitespace issues with `std::cin >> ...`.  (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583652/how-to-read-cin-with-whitespace-up-until-a-newline-character) for a relevant discussion.)

So, something of the form

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string sampleName;
    char middle;

    std::getline(std::cin, sampleName);

    for (int i = 0; i < sampleName.size(); i++)
    {
        if (sampleName[i] == '.')
        {
            middle = sampleName[i-1];
            break;
        }          
    }

    std::cout << middle << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

may work best.  (Click [here](http://ideone.com/jLsqsf) to test.)

Comment: Not much of a discussion in the linked question but the reason for the problem is `operator>>` skips leading whitespaces and reads characters until it reaches a whitespace.

Comment: Thank you Captain Obvlious! Just had to say that.

Answer (score 0):

you hav [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) function to get in a line with spaces. You are getting wrong output because your program is not taking input with spaces correctly.