# Character dispaying

Tags: c++, console

I know this maybe such a wierd question but it stucks me for a couple of days ago.  My assignemnt is to display the students' information and update them using STRUCT type.  Here is my works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct DATE
{
int day;
int month;
int year;
};

struct STUDENT{
char ID[8];
char name[50];
DATE birthday;
char address[100];
float Math;
float English;
float CS;
};


void inputClass(STUDENT* &list, int &n)
{
cout << "Please enter the number of students: ";
cin >> n;
list = new STUDENT[n+1];
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
cout << "Please enter the info of student " << i << endl;

cout << "ID: "; 
cin >> (&list[i]) -> ID; //the same with "list[i].ID"
fflush(stdin);

cout << "Name: ";
cin >> (&list[i]) -> name;
fflush(stdin);

cout << "Date of Birth\n";
cout << "Day: ";
cin >> (&list[i]) -> birthday.day;
fflush(stdin);
cout << "Month: ";
cin >> (&list[i]) -> birthday.month;
fflush(stdin);
cout << "Year: ";
cin >> (&list[i]) -> birthday.year;
fflush(stdin);

cout << "Address: ";
cin >> (&list[i]) -> address;
fflush(stdin);

cout << "Math result: ";
cin >> (&list[i]) -> Math;
fflush(stdin);

cout << "English result: ";
cin >> (&list[i]) -> English;
fflush(stdin);

cout << "CS result: ";
cin >> (&list[i]) -> CS;
fflush(stdin);

cout << "************* Next Student *************\n" ;
}
}

void updateScore(STUDENT* list, int n)
{
cout << "Who do you want to update?" << endl;
cout << "Ordinal Number(s): ";
cin >> n;
//Display outdated results
cout << "Student's Name: " << (&list[n])-> name << endl;
cout << "*********** Current Results ***********" << endl;
cout << "Math: " << (&list[n]) -> Math << endl;
cout << "English: " << (&list[n]) -> English << endl;
cout << "CS: " << (&list[n]) -> CS << endl;
//Update results
cout << "Please update the results" << endl;
cout << "Math result: ";
cin >> (&list[n]) -> Math;
fflush(stdin);

cout << "English result: ";
cin >> (&list[n]) -> English;
fflush(stdin);

cout << "CS result: ";
cin >> (&list[]) -> CS;
fflush(stdin);


}

void main()
{
STUDENT* list;
int n;
inputClass(list, n);

updateScore(list, n);
}
```

In the "//Display outdated result" section, I used "cout" to print out the Name of the regarding student based on his/her ordinal numbers.  However, let's say I want to get the whole name like: "John Smith".  What I have got, however, is only "John".  Is there a way I can get all of the characters?

Many thanks for your help and sorry for my bad English, I am a student from Vietnam.

Comment: Actually, your English is quite good:)

Comment: You should use C++ strings instead of C-style strings

Comment: I'm completely agree with Martin, your English is far away from the robot-like expressions I use ....

Comment: It takes me a very long time to think and type those sentences like that in English. lol

Comment: You are **writting** on the Internet, so you have enough time to think and check for misspellings. Thats the secret ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone for all, it works finally. :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::getline` from the `<string>` header, with a `std::string` variable, instead of `>>` and raw character array.

- The `>>` reads whitespace-separated *words* of input.
- The raw character array doesn't adjust to the needed length, and you risk Undefined Behavior on buffer overflow.

---

In passing, many/most programmers find all UPPERCASE to be an eyesore; it hurts the eyes.

Also, all uppercase is by convention (in C and C++) reserved for macro names.

Comment: I think this is a good point to encourage the use of `std::vector` instead of raw dynamic arrays too. I prefer people getting good knowledge of the C++ language first, and then going to the low-level subset to learn how that magic features actually work.

Comment: can you demonstrate how should I correct my code? Since I'm really new to the programming languagues like C++ :(... Many thanks for your support

Comment: well i could "demonstrate", but i chose not to when i wrote this answer. i think the ability to google is a skill that beginners benefit from honing. there is even a saying about this, "give a man a fish, and you feed him for one day. teach him how to fish, and you feed him for life". or, as we once said, "give a man a grilled fish, and you feed him for a day. set him on fire, and you've dispensed with the problem forever".

Comment: Thank you for all Cheers and hth, I did it. I did change 

    cin >> (&list[i]) -> name;

to

    getline(cin,list[n].name);

and it works!

Comment: Congrats! :-) Now make sure you're using `std::string`, not raw character arrays.

Answer (score 1):

As it's already been answered previously, you should use std::getline (refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583652/how-to-read-cin-with-whitespace-up-until-a-newline-character)).

I'm assuming you're using a IDE, and it usually fixes a lot of things for us, users, but this may turn your code non-compilable in other compilers, so there are some things you should fix to be able to compile your code everywhere:

Always pay attention if you're adding the necessary includes. There's lack of an include statement for stdin and fflush. You should add:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Also, main should return an int, so, it should have been something like

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ /*Although you can usually omit the parameters*/
  // Code

  return 0;
}
```

By the way, just as a side comment, you forgot the subscript at:

```
cout << "CS result: ";
cin >> (&list[]) -> CS;
```

Comment: well, i'm using VS2010 but when I added #include <csdtio> as you said and it says "No such file or directory".  Maybe my code complier is missing something and I should re-install it someday.

...anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark Cheers and hth's answer as accepted, if it has answered your question.