# Weird characters appearing in place of inputted strings

Tags: c++, string, cin

I'm working on a C++ program that takes a string as an input and manipulates it in certain ways. This is the code:

```
string input;
cin >> input;
char arg = input[4]; //All inputs always have 5 characters
cout << arg << endl;
```

Input: add d

I was expecting it to print d to the screen but instead nothing is printed
Also, for other inputs, I sometimes get weird characters (like y with two dots over it) as the output.

Why is this happening and how can it be rectified?

Comment: Mind to post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please?

Comment: After fixing the typo, everything [works as intended](http://ideone.com/E2iBWf).

Comment: You wrote in the comment "all inputs always have 5 characters", but in fact your input 'add d' has only three characters (look at the first token).

Comment: The problem lies with your input - the whitespace (after "add") terminates the input - leaving "add" as the value stored in `input` - so `input[4]` is accessing out of bounds and causing *undefined behavior*

Comment: So how can I take in an input which contains whitespaces?

Comment: @Ajmal For that answer look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583652/how-to-read-cin-with-whitespace-up-until-a-newline-character

Comment: @Ajmal Also, rather than writing a comment "inputs have 5 characters", try to verify that this is actually the case e.g. using an if or assert. Then you can get more information before asking a question such as "why is the length 3 when I think it should be 5".

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: **−1** Posting invalid code (fixed that missing semicolon for you but still don't do that, don't type in code manually: copy and paste)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the extraction of [operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) for `std::string` stops at whitespace, so the value of `input` would be `add`, then `char arg = input[4];` is UB.

> ... then reads characters from `is` and appends them to `str` as if by
>   `str.append(1, c)`, until one of the following conditions becomes
>   true:
>
> - ...
> - `std::isspace(c,is.getloc())` is `true` for the next character `c` in `is` (this whitespace character remains in the input stream).

You can use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead to read input containing whitespaces, it will read the string until the specified delimiter; the default one is the endline. e.g.

```
string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

Comment: I don't see how the standard version matters. For a string with length 3, input[4] is always out of bounds.

Comment: It should be noted that since C++11, `input[3]` would not be undefined behaviour but would indeed return a reference to a null character. However, modifying that reference is still undefined behaviour. In any case, `input[4]` is always undefined behaviour, because the internally used array has only 4 elements (`"add"` plus the null character).

Answer (score 4):

In your input string, the `cin` `>>` operator takes your string until the the space then it will terminate. So in your string only `add` would be present, so when you try to access the fourth character and print nothing will be displayed.

Try,

```
string input;    
getline(cin, input);    
char arg = input[4];    
cout << arg << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example when you input (add d) only the characters before the space are considered.
so there's garbage value in input[4]

If you want to input spaces, use double quotations.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
string input;
cin >> input;
char arg = input[4]; //All inputs always have 5 characters
cout << input.length() << endl;
cout << arg << endl;
}
```

if you pass add d, the string length will be 3, not 5.
If you want to be able to input spaces, replace `cin >> input;`
with `std::getline(std::cin, input);`

and you will get the desired results.